# Returning the text from bs4 find_all function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to fix this(BeautifulSoup):

`crypto_name = soup.find_all("p",class_="sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS") print(crypto_name)`

Which returns:

```
[<p class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS" color="text" font-size="1" font-weight="semibold">Bitcoin</p>, <p class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iJjGCS" color="text" font-size="1" font-weight="semibold">Ethereum</p>
```

I just need it to return Bitcoin and Etherium.I don't really get how to do it though.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add more info about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the result and get the `.text` of teach item.

```
cryptos = [item.text for item in crypto_name]
```

Comment: Thank you so much,didn't realize it had such an easy solution